# Unexpected result while using pipe operator inside a shell variable

Tags: linux, shell, console, stdout

I have a process that dumps some zipped output to the stdout. What I do with this output is pipe and send it through an SSH tunnel to another machine where it is dumped to a file.

Like so:

```
/usr/bin/myapp | ssh root@remotemachine "cat > /path/to/output/file.gz"
```

when I `ssh` to the machine and invoke this line, everything goes fine. But when I put this command in a shell script like

```
#!/bin/sh
APP=/usr/bin/myapp
OPTS=--gzip
OUTPUT= "| ssh root@remotemachine \"cat > /path/to/output/file.gz\""
$APP $OPTS $OUTPUT
```

And then invoke the script, I see garbage on the console, which I can only assume it is the output of `myapp`, and then this

```
Unknown parameter '|'
Unknown parameter 'ssh'
Unknown parameter 'root@remotemachine'
Unknown parameter '"cat'
Unknown parameter '>'
Unknown parameter '/path/to/output/file.gz"'
```

I am guessing that shell sent the `$OUTPUT` section as an argument to `myapp` instead of acting on them. So, these "Unknown parameter" were coming from `myapp` not from the shell.

How I can fix this?

Comment: have you tried /bin/bash instead of /bin/sh ?

Comment: No, the system I am working on does not have bash. I need to restrict the work to ash

Comment: Then you shouldn't use `bash` as a tag.

Comment: ok...removed it. But I was wondering if my problem is not specific to ash and may in fact happen in bash too. So, I wanted to reach a wider audience. Also, at this point I am not where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Ok....I found what I needed. It was the `eval` command. This in fact was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279953/how-to-execute-the-output-of-a-command-within-the-current-shell).

So, the script can be modified this way:

```
#!/bin/sh
APP=/usr/bin/myapp
OPTS=--gzip
OUTPUT= "| ssh root@remotemachine \"cat > /path/to/output/file.gz\""
eval "$APP $OPTS $OUTPUT"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your shell parses any command line in a certain sequence. When it encounters `$APP $OPTS $OUTPUT` it sees there is no pipe operator; later these variables are expanded and `|` appears but it has no special meaning because it's already too late for this.

The result can be re-evaluated with `eval` (your answer shows you have already discovered this) but [`eval` may turn out to be a misspelled `evil`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Your original approach is flawed because shell variables are not meant to contain code. Functions are for code. Example:

```
app=/usr/bin/myapp
opts=--gzip
output() { ssh root@remotemachine "cat > /path/to/output/file.gz"; }
$app $opts | output
```

Note [it is a good practice to use lowercase variable names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/42849/108618).

Comment: I am not an expert at shell scripting. I will try out your answer. It looks better than mine.